# Declaring strings in xml vs java code

Tags: android

I have lots of large strings which I will use only in two places (2 methods). I could declare them globally in the class, but worried about the memory and dynamic memory allocation slowing down the app.

Even though I declare in strings.xml, I would have to load them using `getResources().getString()` Would declaring them in strings.xml make anything better? memory or speed.

I am not worried about localization.

Comment: What are you doing that requires such finely tuned optimization? The performance difference between these two methods of storing strings is going to be negligible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion keeping the strings is `strings.xml` is a better option

> 1) As you will practically save a number of String objects which you would have created during runtime.
>
> 2) Easy to manage all strings at one place.
>
> 3) its better to allocate resources at compile time rather than runtime.

Comment: Yes, exactly. by allocating resources at runtime, you mean getResources().getString() won't allocated additional memory at runtime?

Comment: No it won't. It just a reference to already created string object in Resources.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing in a developer's life is not how well he writes a code but how well he maintains a code so that more people can work on the same

Keeping all strings in strings.xml is a better option to keep them in the same file and also editing/modification of these strings will be easier.

Comment: creating final static string constants in the Java code is also a very good way to code. But its good to understand the most efficient way Android uses, and to keep that practice.

Comment: static constants are class variables they exists as long as app stays running, and are not easily cleared by gc.

Comment: Google suggests to use static final constants https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#UseFinal

Comment: @dcanh121 above link suggests use static final constants instead of static constants. I am suggesting not to use either one :). Hard code the things in strigs.xml if they are not going to change.

Answer (score -2):

Strings.xml is more maintainable and best practice,however if the only thing in the world you care about is efficiency and speed hard code it. There is no correct answer.I hope the string isn't your company name and they get bought out for example.